# octave + gnuplot + os x 10.6 : nothing happens

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, octave, gnuplot

On my first-gen Macbook Pro, with OS X 10.6.1, I can launch gnuplot and get a plot, after I set the terminal to x11, with a command like

plot [-6:6] sin(x).

But when I launch octave, and try a plot command, like

plot([2 3],[4 5]) or plot([-6:0.01:6],cos([-6:0.01:6]))

I get no error messages and no plot. Just another octave prompt. I installed from octave-3.2.3-i386.dmg. What gives?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If gnuplot works after setting the terminal to x11 (`set term x11`), then you could try the same in octave:

```
octave-3.2.3:1> setenv GNUTERM 'x11'
```

I believe that the default terminal of gnuplot on OS X is aquaterm, so it is probably the default terminal when octave is plotting with gnuplot as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have aqua it will work fine.

It seems to me that you have port installed aquaterm and xcode also

Verify with:

```
sudo port installed
```

if exists aqua and you have xcode installed try

```
sudo port uninstall aqua
```